# Multiple Parameters for Onformat

Tags: tinybutstrong

I cannot get TBS to merge one of the fields I reference as a parameter to a function. The eventid gets merged, but eventdate does not. Any thoughts on why?

```
[blk.mp3filename; onformat=f_constructPath; year=[blk.eventdate; frm='YYYY'; noerr]; eventid=[blk.eventid; noerr]; strconv=no; noerr]
```

The eventdate field is present, because I can move the TBS tag to elsewhere on the page and it returns data. I tried using ondata but the function was never called, so I went to using onformat.

```
[blk.mp3filename; ondata=f_constructPath; strconv=no; noerr]
```

Here's a larger part of the code with the ondata statement version:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
        <img class="FBC_thumb" src="_resources/images/persons/[blk.imagefilename; magnet=img; noerr]" alt="[blk.greeting; strconv=no; noerr] [blk.firstname; strconv=no; noerr] [blk.lastname; strconv=no; noerr]">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-10">
        <h3 class="FBC_sermon-title">[blk.title; strconv=no; magnet=div; noerr]</h3>
        <div class="FBC_speakername font-weight-bold"><span>[blk.greeting; magnet=span; strconv=no; noerr] </span>[blk.firstname; magnet=p; strconv=no; noerr] [blk.lastname; magnet=p; strconv=no; noerr]</div>
        <div class="FBC_bioshort">[blk.bioshort; magnet=p; strconv=no; noerr]</div>
        <div>
            <div class="d-sm-inline FBC_eventdate"><span class="font-weight-bold">Date: </span>[blk.eventdate; magnet=div; frm='mmm d, YYYY'; strconv=no; noerr]</div>
            <div class="d-sm-inline pl-sm-3 FBC_eventname"><span class="font-weight-bold">Event: </span>[blk.eventname; magnet=div; strconv=no; noerr]</div>
            <div class="FBC_icon-group">
                <div>
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapsePlayer" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapsePlayer"><span class="d-block icon icon-headphones"></span>
                    <span class="FBC_text-8">LISTEN</span></a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="ministries/sermon-library1/download/[blk.id; magnet=a; mtype=m+m; strconv=no; noerr]/"><span class="d-block icon icon-download"></span>
                    <span class="FBC_text-8">DOWNLOAD</span></a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#modalShare"><span class="d-block icon icon-share2"></span>
                    <span class="FBC_text-8">SHARE</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapsePlayer" class="collapse col-12 pt-4 pb-3">
        <div class="FBC_player-outer-wrapper">
            <div class="FBC_player-wrapper w-100 w-md-75">
                <div class="FBC_seek-slider"></div>
                <div id="FBC_play-pause" class="FBC_player-button icon icon-play3"></div>
                <div class="FBC_player-left-wrapper">
                    <div class="FBC_player-volume-wrapper">
                        <div class="FBC_player-volume icon"><span class="FBC_player-last-volume" style="display: none"></span></div>
                        <div id="display-always" class="FBC_player-volume-slider"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="FBC_player-text"><span id="duration">0:00</span><span id="length"> / 0:00</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="FBC_player-right-wrapper">
                    <div class="FBC_player-quality"><span class="icon icon-cog"></span>
                        <div class="FBC_player-quality-menu display-none">
                            <span class="FBC_player-quality-menu-title">Quality</span>
                            <span id="menuitem" class="FBC_player-quality-menu-item menu-item1 icon">96k</span>
                            <span id="menuitem2" class="FBC_player-quality-menu-item menu-item2 icon">24k</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p id="source1" style="display: none">[blk.mp3filename; block=div; ondata=f_constructPath; strconv=no; noerr]</p>
            <p id="url" style="display: none">[onshow.url; strconv=no; noerr]</p>
            <audio class="FBC_player"></audio>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 pt-4 pb-3">
        <h5>Summary</h5>
        <p class="FBC_summary">[blk.summary; magnet=div; strconv=no; noerr]</p>
    </div>
</div><!-- End Bootstrap Row -->
```

Comment: Embedded fields may be not merged as you expect.  The rules are explained here http://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#html_field. `ondata` seems more appropriate, it works only if you have actually defined a block, that is you have a parameter `block` in at least one field starting with `blk`. Can you give a more complete block definition ?

Comment: I didn't use the block parameter as the SQL call returns only one record, but I did add back in block parameter and it works only if I add the block parameter in the field with the ondata statement. I'll add the full code block to question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a block bound defined for `blk` (that is your have at least one TBS fields with parameter `block`), then it is a normal block merging and parameter `ondata` is processed (like all block parameters in this TBS field).
If the `ondata` function does not behave has you expect, you can debug it by watching what it has for argument `$CurrRec`. For example : `var_export($CurrRec)`.
Please note that block parameters are processed only if they go with a `block` parameter.

If you have no block bound defined for `blk` (that is your have no TBS fields with parameter `block`), then TBS merges only the first record and it behave like a `MerfeField()`. That is, no block parameter is processed. So the `ondata` function is ignored.
In this case you can use `onformat` and you can debug the corresponding function by watching what it has for argument `$CurrPrm`. In you case, according to your snippet, I guess TBS fields embedded in parameter are simply not merged.

One more remark: in your piece of template, you have some TBS fields inside the block, and some other outside the block. Outside fields will be merged separately from normal block section.